# C# Singleton Initialisation

Tags: c#, singleton, remoting

I've created a simple C# remoting server/client with the view of replicating an existing VB6 ActiveX exe.

The client creates a server activated singleton object correctly. The object is only very simple having the one property - a Count. Each client that runs creates the object and increments its Count.

Simple - multiple clients are each working with the same Simpleton object and the Count property can be incremented by each.

However... if I leave a client open for any length of time - say, for example, a couple of minutes - when it the client increments the object's Count property, suddenly the Count property has been initialised to zero - across all clients. It's as though the remote 
object has been destroyed and recreated despite the object only ever being retrieved from the server once - when the client opens.

Any thoughts appreciated,

Thanks
MM

Comment: can you declare count as static variable, or application variable as it is share-able  across all other instances

Comment: Can you show us some of the relevant code?

Comment: Can you show us some code so what we can give you a mode detailed answer?

Comment: where are your client and server processes running? IIS for instance may restart the app-domain, so that your singleton is destroyed and recreated with a "count" of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to override the lifetime of the remote object:

```
public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
        return null; //remote object lease time forever
    }
```

Place that into your class which inherits MarshalByRefObject